# What is wrong with this SQL statement for cs50 problem set 7?

Tags: sql, sqlite, cs50, intersect

What is wrong with this statement? It results in no output.

```
select title from movies where id in 
(select movie_id from stars where person_id in 
(select id from people where name="Johnny Depp" intersect 
select id from people where name="Helena Bonham Carter"));
```

Comment: Shouldn't even syntax , there is no intersect in mysql, search mysql intersect for alternatives.

Comment: CS50 uses sqlite, not mysql.

Comment: Your syntax has an issue. With intersect, you need to build two SQL query. Check this website for the usage; https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-intersect/

Comment: The following statement works:
select title from movies where id in (select movie_id from stars where person_id in (select id from people where name="Johnny Depp") intersect select movie_id from stars where person_id in (select id from people where name="Helena Bonham Carter"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
select id from people where name="Johnny Depp" 
intersect 
select id from people where name="Helena Bonham Carter"
```

returns the **common** results of the 2 queries, but since `id` is the unique primary key of the table `people` there is no case that it will return anything.
Simpler: if the 1st query returns 10 and the 2nd returns 20 the intersection of 10 and 20 does not exist.
 
You can get the result that you want with joins:

```
select distinct m.title
from movies m
inner join stars s1 on s1.movie_id = m.id 
inner join stars s2 on s2.movie_id = m.id 
inner join people p1 on p1.id = s1.person_id and p1.name = 'Johnny Depp'
inner join people p2 on p2.id = s2.person_id and p2.name = 'Helena Bonham Carter'
```

Comment: Nice explanation. `m` after movies is an allias?

Comment: Yes, every table needs an alias.